# Populate nested object from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a question, how to create nested object from array?
I.e. I have a following array:

`var myArr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`
and need to make it an object like:

`myObj = {foo: { bar: { baz: { } } }}`

How can I do that properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var myArr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var myObj = {};

myArr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[b] = {};
  return a[b];
}, myObj);

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do better ! :

```js
let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

let obj = arr.reduceRight((a,c)=>({[c]:a}),{})

document.write( JSON.stringify(obj) )
```

Using [.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) method