# Convert list of Objects when the levels are given in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Suppose I have an array which tells me the list of labels and a value that I need to add them into a JSON object. How do you transform it so?

So basically I have is an array and a value `100`

```
arr = ["1", "Male"]
```

Should be transform it into a object as so.

```
obj = {
    "1":{
        "Male":100
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would happen with an array like `['1', 'Male', 'Female']` or `['Female']`? Would you then get `{'1': { 'Male': { 'Female': 100 } } }` or `{ 'Female': 100 }`?

Comment: Here's a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054601/populate-nested-object-from-array

Comment: @Barmar, this target assigns for each level amn object without checking, if a value/object exists.

Comment: @NinaScholz Not sure what you mean. It creates the object at each level, how can it not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the last property and reduce the object. At the end assign the value to the last property.

This solution respects already given properties.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
   var last = path.pop();
   path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = {};

setValue(object, ["1", "Male"], 100);
console.log(object);

setValue(object, ["1", "Female"], 200);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So I upvoted it when first answering myself, but it keeps me occupied in so far that I believe it's a bit overly complicated, and it doesn't as much create an object as does it mutate a given argument, and I'm not sure the OP wants that. Not only that but how the value gets added is a bit obscure (and I do think that's why you mutate rather than create), so I am in doubt :)

Comment: @Icepickle this kind of questions tends to a later wanted upgrade that the function should keep all properties and add just a new one. and while this function already works with an empty object, there is noting obscure. the functionality is straight forward, from the array of properties is the last one store and for all other, the reducing takes place which returns either a known property or add a new property to the last object. finally the last property is take for assigning a value.

Comment: That's a nice assumption, I was only talking about how you added the last property, which you couldn't have done in case you would return the object, so in that way, I found it a bit obfuscated (is probably a better word than obscure). The only other thing is that I am not a big fan of mutating arguments, cause that leads to side effects which the OP might not expect yet :) I guess in a sense, you could create another function to create a new object, set the value on that and return it, then the OP has 2 ways to go about it

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceright) for this. Use `value` as the `initialValue` of reduce and create a new level of nesting in every loop.

```js
function createObj(paths, value) { 
  return paths.reduceRight((r, key) =>  ({ [key] : r }), value)  
}

console.log(createObj(["1", "Male"], 100))
console.log(createObj(["level 1", "level 2", "level 3" ], "value"))
```