# How to set nested object with dynamic keys on javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let foo = {};

const key1 = 'a';
const key2 = 'b';
const key3 = 'c';

foo[key1][key2][key3] = [1, 2];
```

When I trying to do something similar I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
```

Comment: In that given codesnippet you are trying to access key1 in foo which is undefined. Undefined is the default value that a given key in a json object will be considered as. However you are then trying to access a KEY VALUE from foo[key1] where foo[key1] = undefined. Assign appropriate key value pairs in the json and it should work

Comment: if you are using lodash, `_.get` for reading object's value through a dot-notation string, `_.set` for setting object's dot-notation nested value. lodash doc  [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create the nested object before you can create a property in it.

```js
let foo = {}

const key1 = 'a'
const key2 = 'b'
const key3 = 'c'

foo[key1] = {};
foo[key1][key2] = {};
foo[key1][key2][key3] = [1, 2];
console.log(foo);
```

If the list of keys is generated dynamically in an array, see [Populate nested object from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054601/populate-nested-object-from-array?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a function to create all the objects.

Comment: I would have demonstrated with: `console.log(foo.a.b.c);`

Answer (score 5):

You can also create the literal object with dynamic keys.  Just make sure to create nested objects where necessary as @Barmar demonstrated.

```js
const key1 = 'a'
const key2 = 'b'
const key3 = 'c'

let foo = { [key1]: { [key2]: { [key3]: [1, 2] } } };

console.log(foo.a.b.c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will make this possible, however the keys need to be in a list and in reverse order.

```js
const key1 = 'a'
const key2 = 'b'
const key3 = 'c'

const foo = [key3, key2, key1].reduce((a,c)=>({[c]:a}), [1, 2]);

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which takes three parameters:

- The object on which keys will be added.
- The array of keys in order.
- The value which will be set to the last level.

Use `forEach` loop to loop though the keys. Except for last index add empty `{}` to the key. And change the current object to that empty object.

```js
let foo = {}

function nestedKey(obj,keys,value){
  keys.forEach((x,i) => {
    obj[x] = i === keys.length -1 ? value : {};
    obj = obj[x]
  })
}
nestedKey(foo,['a','b','c'],[1,2]);

console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (improved Barmar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56637638/860099) without keys repetition)

```js
let foo = {}, t;

const key1 = 'a';
const key2 = 'b';
const key3 = 'c';

t= foo[key1]= {};
t= t[key2]= {};
t[key3]= [1, 2];

console.log(foo);
```

If `foo` has more (nested) values they will be saved