# How do i create an object by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create an object by an array like:

```js
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and the object would be:

```js
{"a": { "b" : { "c": {}}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: Try a recursive function.

Comment: @MisterJojo Don't just rely on console.log. Try to understand the logic. Its perfectly valid and much more efficient than yours.

Comment: @MisterJojo I see there is not much difference in performance test between both code variants. Even your code performed slightly better. However it is not my duty to explain you if you are not able to understand some logic.

Comment: @MohammadUsman even if it is faster, a false code remains a false code. I find it hard to believe that your argument is to belittle me rather than prove the correctness of its code, it's pathetic

Comment: see my new second answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054601/populate-nested-object-from-array/61601697#61601697