# Get parent array from child array

Tags: javascript

In the code below I can easily enter into a subarray within the array with `current = current[0]`.

```js
var root = [
  [
    'Value 1',
  ]
];
var current = root;

current = current[0];

current.push('Value 2');

document.write(JSON.stringify(root));
```

How can I do the reverse and go up a level? In this example, `current` would become:

```
[['Value 1', 'Value 2']]
```

The only way I can think of doing this would be looping, but duplicates would be very probably and problematic. All I've found online is looping, which won't work as a mention in the last sentence.

**EDIT**

I'm looping through a large string and converting it to a tree. Certain characters will require a indent in the tree or a separate branch, while others will require an outdent and return to the parent function. I've achieved the indents by having a `current` variable just enter a new subarray as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684251/create-json-object-tree-from-looped-string-without-using-eval?#answer-62684338). I just need a way to exit with a different character.

Comment: There is no way to walk back up... Unclear why you would need to do it. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You can't, but if you expand on the problem you are trying to solve we might be able to help you with an algorithm

Comment: @epascarello It is very unclear, sorry. I've edited my answer to try to include more information on why I'm using the approach.

Comment: @AdrianBrand, Can you check my edited answer? Hopefully it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Arrays have no concept of a "parent" or anything. They don't care where their references are being held. However, if you really really need to, you can implement the concept of a "parent" yourself using a simple recursive function setting properties of the arrays - see below:

```js
var root = [
  [
    'Value 1',
  ]
];

function setParents(root) {
  for(var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
    if(Array.isArray(root[i])) {
      root[i].parent = root;
      setParents(root[i]);
    }
  }
}

setParents(root);

var current = root;
current = current[0];
current.push('Value 2');
document.write(JSON.stringify(root));

current = current.parent;
console.log(current);
```

This makes use of the fact that array properties don't show up when logged or serialized as JSON, only their elements. So they're kind of "hidden" in a sense. It's a bit hacky but could work for you.

However, I recommend you simply avoid overwriting `current` - there's not really a great need to use it like a cursor traversing some hierarchy structure.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I turn the arrays into objects with a parent value and an actual value? Would it be possible to then edit the parent?

Comment: @Jack See my edited answer, there's a sample of a recursive function you could implement on top of your existing code without much hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, seems like just what I need. If I were to run `current = current.parent` and then push a value, would that change `root` or is it just in the array properties?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pushing BEFORE setting current variable will work.

```js
var root = [
  [
    'Value 1',
  ]
];
var current = root;

root.push("AAA");

current = current[0];

current.push('Value 2');

document.write(JSON.stringify(root));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the rest of my code greatly depends on `current` so removing would require me to rewrite it (not the worst), but I have no idea how to do it without using a "cursor"