# How to convert an array of paths to an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an array of paths:

```
const paths = [
    "/path/to/first",
    "/path/to/second",
    "/path/to/third",
    "/path/from/first",
    "/path/from/second",
    "/users/bill",
    "/users/john"
];
```

I'd like to convert this to a javascript object of this form:

```
{
    path: {
        to: {
            first,
            second,
            third
        },
        from: {
            first,
            second
        }
    },
    users: {
        bill,
        john
    }
}
```

How would I do this using pure javascript (not jQuery, and not using JSON.parse or other shortcuts).

If necessary, the end points can be key:value pairs that point to "null" for example:

```
user: {
     bill: null,
     john: null
}
```

I'm hoping for a non-recursive solution, but if this is significantly simpler with recursion, then that's ok!

Comment: What have you tried? JSON.parse is "pure" JavaScript, not sure what you mean by it being a shortcut, and doesn't apply to the question in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You should split the strings with a delimiter of `/`, which should result in an array like `['', 'path', 'to', 'first']` for the first path in the array. Then its as simple as checking if `path` is in the array, if so, is `to` in the array, if so, add `first` to obj.path.to.

Something like (and this could be refactored more, its a 0th pass attempt)

```js
const obj = {
  path: {
    to: {
    },
    from: {
    }
  },
  users: {
  }
}
for (let path of paths) {
  const pathArr = path.split('/');
  if (pathArr.includes('path') && pathArr.includes('to')) {
    obj.path.to[pathArr[3]] = null;
  }
  else if (pathArr.includes('path') && pathArr.includes('from')) {
    obj.path.from[pathArr[3]] = null;
  }
  ...
}
```

and so on.

Obviously this could be made more efficient, dynamically creating the keys `path`, `to`, `from`, and `users`, but this would work

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to do it. It can only handle up to three though. You can try expanding it if you want.

```js
const paths = [
  "/path/to/first",
  "/path/to/second",
  "/path/to/third",
  "/path/from/first",
  "/path/from/second",
  "/users/bill",
  "/users/john"
];

const res = paths.reduce((acc, path) => {
  const [first, second, third] = path.split("/").filter((a) => a);
  if (first && !acc[first]) acc[first] = {};
  if (second && !acc[first][second]) acc[first][second] = {};
  if (third && !acc[first][second][third]) acc[first][second][third] = {};
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version built atop some simple helper functions:

```js
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})

const build = (ps) => 
  hydrate (ps .map (p => [p .slice (1) .split ('/'), null]))

const paths = ["/path/to/first", "/path/to/second", "/path/to/third", "/path/from/first", "/path/from/second", "/users/bill", "/users/john"]

console .log (build (paths))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here, `setPath` takes a path such as `['path', 'to', 'first']`, and a value such as `null` and an object and returns a copy of that object, setting the value at that path, creating any intermediate nodes as needed. `hydrate` takes an array of path-value pairs and creates a brand new object as needed.

Our `build` function then splits the paths on `"/"`, maps each to a `[['path', 'to', 'first'], null]`-style entry, and then passes the resulting array to `hydrate`.

Recursion makes this code simpler.  We could write `setPath` in a more imperative way, using iteration versus recursion, but I would expect much uglier code for very little benefit.  I'd love to be proven wrong on this, though.

Comment: It appears that the power that be closed this question as being "already answered" here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054601/populate-nested-object-from-array

... which is odd, because it seems to me that my question has substantial differences, one being that if I have multiple paths, I need those extra paths to be included in the same javascript object. It doesn't seem like the reduce function from the other post solves that issue.

Comment: While that's perhaps not the right duplicate, there certainly have been plenty of questions like this.  The tools in my answer were created in response to [other similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20hydrate).  But a second round of reduce would convert that into a solution to one that solves yours.  Mine uses recursion rather than reducing for the innermost part, but either would work.  Finally, "the powers that be" are those trying diligently to keep this the best programming Q & A site available.  Closing duplicates is a big part of that.