# Unflat array javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't figure it out how to 'unflat' the object below.

The criteria for the parent > child relationship is the number property, like so: 1 (parent) > 1.1 (child)

It's parcially correct. The `.map()` end up repeating items that were already in the theirs parent objects.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'task a', number: '1' },
  { name: 'task b', number: '1.1'},
  { name: 'task c', number: '1.2' },
  { name: 'task d', number: '2' },
  { name: 'task e', number: '2.1' },
  { name: 'task f', number: '2.1.1' }
];

const output = arr.map((element) => {
  const re = new RegExp(`^(${element.number}\.)\\d$`)
  element.subRows = arr.filter((e) => {
    return e.number.match(re)
  })
  return element
})

output.forEach((x) => {
  console.log(x)
})
```

Expected output:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'task a',
    number: '1',
    subRows: [
      {
        name: 'task b',
        number: '1.1',
        subRows: []
      },
      {
        name: 'task c',
        number: '1.2',
        subRows: []

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'task d',
    number: '2',
    subRows: [
      {
        name: 'task e',
        number: '2.1',
        subRows: [
          {
            name: 'task f',
            number: '2.1.1',
            subRows: []
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: You're code only creates the second level, it doesn't recurse. A better approach would be to use `element.number.split('.')` and then use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054601/populate-nested-object-from-array?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first do a sort to ensure a preorder traversal of the final tree, then do a reduce from left to construct it. Normally, just knowing the preorder traversal won't be sufficient to construct a tree but here we also know the depths of the nodes so it is possible.

```js
const arr = [
      { name: 'task a', number: '1' },
      { name: 'task b', number: '1.1'},
      { name: 'task c', number: '1.2' },
      { name: 'task g', number: '1.1.1'},
      { name: 'task d', number: '2' },
      { name: 'task e', number: '2.1' },
      { name: 'task f', number: '2.1.1' }
    ];

let tree = arr.sort((x,y) => x.number.localeCompare(y.number)).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let currDepth = 0;
    let targetDepth = Math.floor((curr.number.length-1)/2);
    let obj = acc;
    while (currDepth <= targetDepth) {
        if (currDepth == targetDepth)
            obj.subRows.push({ name : curr.name, number : curr.number, subRows : [] });
        else
            obj = obj.subRows.at(-1);
        currDepth++;
    }
    return acc;
}, { subRows : []})

console.log(tree.subRows)
```